Get a bean which has a parameterized constructor
@Component
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class Programmer {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("laptop")
    private Computer machine;

    private final int salary;

    public Programmer(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    void code() {
        System.out.println("Programmer is coding with " + machine.getClass().getName());
    }
}



I want to get a bean of this component and set different salary for different objects of this class.
I tried looking for something relevant but couldn't find anything.
I got solution like doing:
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.classbasedconfig")
public class config {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="prototype")
    public Programmer programmer() {
        return new Programmer(1000);
    }
}



or using @Value annotation. But I want to get beans with different values for salary i.e. I need n numbers of Programmer objects with different salaries. How do I do this? I do not want to use XML based config. Is this possible?

This use case does not seem to match the concept of a bean. We use beans if there is a small number of instances (in most cases: exactly one) of a class or interface. Can you please elaborate your use case? --- A word of advice: do not mix constructor- and field injection. Even better: do not use field injection at all.

@Turing85 I am learning spring so I had this question. "This use case does not seem to match the concept of a bean. We use beans if there is a small number of instances (in most cases: exactly one) of a class or interface." and this answers most of my questions. But if we are not creating field injections then how are we going to set the properties?

"But if we are not creating field injections then how are we going to set the properties?" - Search for "constructor injection".

@Turing85 ohh I read this but I was wondering if there was a different method. Thank you very much for the help:)
